# can anyone help me please I want to change my mascot image to pixel image when I hover to mascot image how should I do that?

Tags: html, css

Can anyone help me please I want to change my mascot image to pixel image when I hover to mascot image how should I do that?

This is my CSS:

```
.mascot {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 15vw;
    border-radius: 11vw;
}
 .pixel {
    display: none;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 15vw;
    border-radius: 11vw;
}
```

And this is my HTML markup:

```
<div class="hoverimg">
    <img class="mascot" src="mascot.png" alt="">
    <img src="download.png" alt="" class="pixel">
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'pixel image'?

Answer (score 1):

try this!

```
<div class="jb-a">
      <img src="mascot.png" alt="" class="jb-b">
      <img src="download.png" alt="" class="jb-c">
</div>
```

```
      .jb-a {
        width: 400px;
        margin: 0px auto;
        position: relative
      }
      .jb-c {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        display: none;
      }
      .jb-a:hover .jb-c {
        display: block;
      }
```

Comment: Upvoted your answer this time, but next time, don't answer questions that will be closed. Doing so promotes vague and unspecific questions. Thanks!

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE I'll keep your advice in mind next time! Thanks!